# Novice programmer - Few Questions

Tags: search

essentially I have decided to write a program to help expedite a process I normally do manually. I don't have much programming experience at all, so I figured I'd ask yall for some advice!

**Here is what I need to do:**
-Search through an online database (a website) and compare a number to an existing number I have on file.
-There is extra information in the database that I don't care about
-The database does have a "pattern" so to say and is about 5000 items long.

**My Questions:**
Typically I like to do things and learn on my own but I have a few concerns

-What is the best language and program to use for this task? In high school I had a little experience with java/eclipse but since then nothing.
-How fast can a program like this execute? The database only lists 10 items per page, and since there are about 5000 items it would take about 500 page loads to run.
-How tough is a program like this? Is it something I can do by myself in a reasonable time or should I outsource it?

Thank you all in advance for the help!

EDIT: 
Also, this is what I perceive the pseudo code to look like.

```
RUN
Load Webpage
Search Page
IF match found alert user
ELSE load next page
IF last page go to first page and start again
```

Comment: Try not to ask many questions per post; also try not to post questions asking for opinions of the community. You should try something first and then ask specific questions.

Comment: "Novice programmer - Few Questions" describes you and the settings for your post. It does not describe the post itself, nor does it help people figure out if they are interested in the question/answers.

Answer (score 0):

Naming the best language would be subjective.  You could approach this with a website running PHP and the CURL library.  Or you could do it with python.  What your doing is often called scraping so you could start by  researching page scraping and web crawlers.

Answer (score 0):

-What is the best language and program to use for this task? In high school I had a little experience with java/eclipse but since then nothing.

Any web related language is ok. As matter a fact any language will do, but with a language that is more related to the web will be easier. Ex.: PHP, JS, Java, Ruby, Python, several others.

-How fast can a program like this execute? The database only lists 10 items per page, and since there are about 5000 items it would take about 500 page loads to run.

Really fast. Couple seconds.

-How tough is a program like this?

I consider it very easy. Depends on the knowledge you have with the language you coose. But even if you have to learn it from 0, it's not a difficult task.

-Is it something I can do by myself in a reasonable time or should I outsource it?

You definitely can do it yourself.